# when can I say that $UV^T$ is a permutation matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector

suppose we have two p.s.d matrices A and B: so we can diagonalize them like this:
A= $UΛU^T$ and $B=VΣV^T$

1: on what condition for $A$ and $B$ I can say that $UV^T$ is a permutation matrix?

2: how can I make a index for calculating how much $UV^T$ is similar to a permutation matrix?

suppose we have descending order for $Λ$ and increasing order for $Σ$ .

$U$ and $V$ are unitary and their cluomns are orthonormal.

Comment: "make an index"? what's that?

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that $U$ and $V$ are unitary?

Comment: yes, $U$ and $V$ are unitary and their cluomns are orthonormal. thanks for help

Comment: @ DimaPasechnik: I mean i need a measure

Comment: If you want to define a "distance from being a permutation matrix", the obvious candidate is $$\min_{P \in \text{Permutation matrices}} \|A-P\|,$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is a matrix norm.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $U^T V$? If we permute the order of the entries in $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma$, this multiplies $U^T V$ by permutation matrices, so this condition is independent of how you order the entries.

Comment: If $U^T V$ is a permutation $P$, then $AB=BA$. (Proof: $AB = U \Lambda P \Sigma V^T = U \Lambda \Sigma' P V^T = U \Lambda \Sigma' U^T$, where $\Sigma'= P \Sigma P^{-1}$, and $BA = V \Sigma V^T U \Lambda U^T = V \Sigma P^{-1} \Lambda U^T = V P^{-1} \Sigma' \Lambda U^T = U \Sigma' \Lambda U^T$. Since $P$ is permutation, $\Sigma'$ is diagonal, and $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma'$ commute.) Conversely, if $A$ and $B$ commute, then we can choose $U$ and $V$ so that $U^T V$ is permutation.

Comment: won't U = V = reflection matrix  do?

Comment: @ David Speyer:thanks,that is true and helped, but i am looking for all matrices $A$ and $B$ with this property.

Comment: @math2014 So, are you saying that what you want is $U^T V$ a permutation as I suggested? In that case, why not use $|AB-BA|$ (for whichever matrix norm you like best)?

Comment: @David Speyer :Many many thanks, you really helped,  "Conversely, if A and B commute, then we can choose U and V so that $U^TV$ is permutation" I just want descending order for Λ and increasing order for Σ , ,so how can I find that way, to see if it is like that or not? if the the answer of this question is yes, then $ |AB−BA|$ is a good measure:)